# Add a Vertical Rule From a Specified Row to the End

Tags: tables

I have written the below code to generate a table

```
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc|cccc}
    \hline \rl{داده} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ UCR1 + V1 } & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{ UCR2 + V2 } \\
    \hline \rl{الگوریتم} & HS & MT & R + HS & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{MT}$ & $\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{MT}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{MT}$ \\
    $n$& & & & & & & & \\
    \hline 50 & 6 & 2 & 7 & 6 & 10 & 3 & 5 & 5 \\
    100 & 20 & 6 & 16 & 16 & 31 & 5 & 11 & 9 \\
    250 & 103 & 12 & 70 & 68 & 175 & 13 & 65 & 65 \\
    500 & 392 & 27 & 250 & 240 & 627 & 18 & 120 & 111 \\
    \hline \rl{داده} & & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$\mathrm{SCR}+\mathrm{V} 1$} & & & & & \\
    \hline \rl{الگوریتم} & HS & MT & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{MT}$ & & & & \\
    $n$ & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline 10 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 2 & & & & \\
    30 & 74 & 22 & 74 & 23 & & & & \\
    50 & 749 & 117 & 748 & 117 & & & & \\
    100 & 5400 & 409 & 5380 & 411 & & & &\\
    \hline
    \rl{داده} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{WCR1$+$V1} & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{WCR2}\\
    \hline
    & & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{V1} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{V2}\\
    \cline{6-9}
    \rl{الگوریتم} & HS & MT & R$+$HS & R$+$MT & HS & MT & HS & MT\\
    $n$ & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    50 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 15 & 2\\
    100 & 7 & 1 & 25 & 21 & 13 & 1 & 26 & 2 \\
    250 & 32 & 4 & 130 & 110 & 60 & 4 & 139 & 5 \\
    500 & 115 & 9 & 460 & 400 & 225 & 7 & 430 & 10\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Which has generated the table below
[image] How can I add a vertical line between V1 and V2 in the bottom right of the table separating MT and HS entries going all the way down?

Comment: Although it is not directly related to your problem, please provide a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you set up your document. The reason is: I would like to show you a solution using the `tabularray` package, but I have currently no idea how you setup your document for Arabic/Persian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `tabularray` package which provides a lot of flexibility regarding cell borders (I don't know much about how to setup Persian documents, so my preamble is kind of guesswork):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Amiri}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = { *{9}{X[c,b]} },
    hline{1,2,3,7,13,14,16,Z} = {1-Z}{},
    hline{8,9} = {1-5}{},
    hline{15} = {6-Z}{},
    vline{2,6} = {1-Z}{},
    vline{8} = {14-Z}{},
    cell{1}{2} = {c=4}{c},
    cell{1}{6} = {c=4}{c},
    cell{7}{2} = {c=4}{c},
    cell{13}{2} = {c=4}{c},
    cell{13}{6} = {c=4}{c},
    cell{14}{1} = {r=2}{c},
    cell{14}{6} = {c=2}{c},
    cell{14}{8} = {c=2}{c}
}
    \rl{داده} & $\mathrm{UCR1}+\mathrm{V1}$ & & & & $\mathrm{UCR2}+\mathrm{V2}$ & & & \\
    { \rl{الگوریتم} \\ $n$ } & $\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{MT}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{MT}$ & $\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{MT}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{MT}$ \\
    50 & 6 & 2 & 7 & 6 & 10 & 3 & 5 & 5 \\
    100 & 20 & 6 & 16 & 16 & 31 & 5 & 11 & 9 \\
    250 & 103 & 12 & 70 & 68 & 175 & 13 & 65 & 65 \\
    500 & 392 & 27 & 250 & 240 & 627 & 18 & 120 & 111 \\
    \rl{داده} & $\mathrm{SCR}+\mathrm{V1}$ & & & & & & \\
    { \rl{الگوریتم} \\ $n$ } & $\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{MT}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{MT}$ & & & & \\
    10 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 2 & & & & \\
    30 & 74 & 22 & 74 & 23 & & & & \\
    50 & 749 & 117 & 748 & 117 & & & & \\
    100 & 5400 & 409 & 5380 & 411 & & & &\\
    \rl{داده} & $\mathrm{WCR1}+\mathrm{V1}$ & & & & $\mathrm{WCR2}$ & & & \\
    { \rl{الگوریتم} \\ $n$ } & & & & & $\mathrm{V1}$ & & $\mathrm{V2}$ & \\
    & $\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{MT}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{R}+\mathrm{MT}$ & $\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{MT}$ & $\mathrm{HS}$ & $\mathrm{MT}$ \\
    50 & 3 & 1 & 9 & 7 & 7 & 2 & 15 & 2\\
    100 & 7 & 1 & 25 & 21 & 13 & 1 & 26 & 2 \\
    250 & 32 & 4 & 130 & 110 & 60 & 4 & 139 & 5 \\
    500 & 115 & 9 & 460 & 400 & 225 & 7 & 430 & 10 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]